# How to remove a point from HashSet<Point>

Tags: android, hashset

I have a HashSet were I can add some Point, but removing is not working for me.
I tried also to make a function. 
How can I fix this?

```
HashSet<Point> array= new HashSet<Point>();

// add some elements:
    array.add(new Point (pos[0],pos[1]));

// remove a element (is not working...)
array.remove(new Point (pos[0],pos[1]));


// tried also to make a function:

    private void removePoint(HashSet<Point> array, final int[] pos) {
            Point pTmp;
            Point rPos = new Point (pos[0],pos[1]);
            final Iterator<Point> it = array.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                pTmp = it.next();
                if (pTmp.equals(rPos)){
                    it.remove(); 
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Where does **Point** come from? I.e are you sure comparing two Point instances compares Point coordinates and does not use default Java comparison which does not (afaik) return true for ; new Point(0, 1).equals(new Point(0, 1)) .

Comment: @harism: it comes from:
import android.graphics.Point;

Answer (score 1):

Typically when I see situations where something is not being removed from a Set, it's because hashCode or equals haven't been implemented properly. Now clearly, if you're using Java Point, I suspect this won't be the case.  If you're using your own 'Point' class, then you need to make sure you override hashCode and equals.